# Getting the package name of the app that currently holds role HOME

Tags: android

Is there a way to query the package name of the app that currently holds a given role e.g. Role.HOME?

I was browsing the source code of the [settings app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/refs/tags/android-cts-8.0_r18/src/com/android/settings/applications/defaultapps/DefaultHomePicker.java) and saw that they're using `packageManager.getHomeActivites()`, but this code is not current. In the current stable release, there's no reference to any such method.